# Pending reviews: Is everybody fasting or what?

Tags: discussion, review

At the moment there are ~50 posts awaiting a review, honestly since I have the opportunity to go through such chains there were times that number has increased to around 70, but what I want to say please be active and go through your review chains!

I know SE sites where I have the same opportunities but rarely have the chance to review as the amount of awaiting reviews is <<10.

Comment: Me, I'm just happy it's not still in the triple-digits.

Comment: @goldPseudo would that have any consequences on the site?

Comment: nothing directly, afaik. just a red flag that nobody cares enough about the site to bother curating it.

Comment: I saw 0 low quality posts in queue today! Big improvement :)

Comment: @nim I'm not keeping all my post up-to-date so as lately stated by goldPseudo in the chat we are now at times reaching only "one digit".

Comment: Interesting... this got bumped during Ramadan, and it's true again this Ramadan!